# Array to string conversion error in Magento logs

Tags: php, magento

My Magento system.log is full with this error:
Notice: Array to string conversion in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 1232.

I've added the code here: (rule 1232 is $key = implode('|', $key);)

```
   /**
      * Get Key for caching block content
      *
      * @return string
      */
     public function getCacheKey()
     {
         if ($this->hasData('cache_key')) {
             return $this->getData('cache_key');
         }
         /**
         * don't prevent recalculation by saving generated cache key
          * because of ability to render single block instance with different data
          */
         $key = $this->getCacheKeyInfo();
         //ksort($key);  // ignore order
         $key = array_values($key);  // ignore array keys
         $key = implode('|', $key);
         $key = sha1($key);
         return $key;
    }
```

Do you know what's going wrong, and what I need to change?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well this is magento core code so i do expect some wrong value getting into $key variable from outside of this code.

You can try to log the $key variable and check if it is an array.

**Something like:**

Mage::log(print_r($key,true), null, 'mycustomerror.log', true);

or

Mage::log($key, null, 'mycustomerror.log', true);

If you want a better answer you should tell us when this notice is generated and the modules you are using.

## After extra info

Well it is a guess because the information you gave me is not much. But your logs shows the following:

```
2013-01-17T16:52:36+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => CATALOG_PRODUCT_HIGHLIGHT
    [1] => 1
    [2] => default
    [3] => a058
    [4] => 0
    [5] => highlight/product/grid.phtml
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 4
    [8] => Array
        (
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
        )

    [11] => Aanbiedingen
    [12] => highlight-special
    [13] => special_from_date,special_to_date
    [14] => -special
    [15] => product_special
)
```

I think the problem is:

```
[8] => Array()
[9] => Array()
[10] => Array()
```

When they are imploded they will give the notice.

**SEE:**
http://codepad.viper-7.com/qb5tIW

I would check the CATALOG_PRODUCT_HIGHLIGHT (highlight/product/grid.phtml)

You can navigate your site so that the highlight/product/grid.phtml is loaded and see if this call is indeed putting that notice in your log files.

good luck !

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where should I place that Mage code?

Comment: I would put it after the line:

//ksort($key);  // ignore order


This will make a new log file that you can find in /var/log/

Comment: Okay thank you, I did that. I've added your first code. Now we have to wait for the new log. ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will check that this weekend!

Answer (score 0):

After noticing one visit to my site's homepage made 90+ lines of this warning in `system.log`, I tackled the problem of nested arrays inferred in khoekman's answer. *My Magento version is 1.7.0.1*

**Step 1**
Create the path: `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block` and then <kbd>cd</kbd> to that directory.

**Step 2**
Copy Abstract.php from core to local:
<kbd>cp</kbd> `~/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php .`
*This is how you "override the core file" for your custom edits.*

**Step 3**
Open the new file `~/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php` in your favorite editor, scroll down to line 1232:

Change from this:
    `$key = implode('|', $key );`
to:
    `$key = $this->implodeRecursive('|', $key );`

**Step 4**
Scroll above this current function `public function getCacheKey()` and then in the free space above it, add in the recursive implode function:

```
//  ckck: fix of system.log Notice: Array to string conversion in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php on line 1232
private function implodeRecursive( $_glue, $_arrIn ) {
    $_arrTmp=Array();
    if( count( $_arrIn ) > 1 ) {
        foreach( $_arrIn as $key => $value ) {
            if( is_string($value) || is_null($value) )
                $_arrTmp[] = $value;
            else
                $_arrTmp[] = $this->implodeRecursive( $_glue, $value );
        }
    }
    $_strReturn = implode( $_glue, $_arrTmp );
    return $_strReturn;
}
```

Through trial and error, the only reliable test was if `$value` is a string. My usual tricks of `is_array()` or testing for `count() > 0` did not work. Fixing this bug was an interesting endeavor.

**Step 5**
Save then close `Abstract.php` and then check in the new file into your version control system.
I use git with [merge --no-ff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff/14865661#14865661) branching.