# How to keep a branch synchronized/updated with master?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

At the moment git is doing my head in, I cannot come up with the best solution for the following.

There are two branches, one called **master** and one called **mobiledevicesupport**. I want to keep mobiledevicesupport as a continuous branch that will be merged/synced with the master branch whenever mobiledevicesupport is stable. This would merge changes from mobiledevicesupport into master but also bring all the changes from master into mobiledevicesupport so that branch can continue to be worked on and the features improved or amended. This needs to work with a central repository and multiple developers.

Please an example of similar workflows other people use or just tell me if this idea is stupid and I should consider other options. At the moment the workflow seems sound, but I just don't know how I can make git work this way.

Thanks, all help much appreciated.

Update 1:
If I was to merge master into mobiledevicesupport and mobiledevice support into master, do I get replicated commits across both branches. Or is git smart enough to work out that I have pulled the latest changes from branch A into branch B and add merge commit C to branch B. And I have pulled the latest changes from branch B into branch A and add merge commit D to branch A?

I was going to post an image but I don't have enough reputation for it, so I guess the following illustration will have to do. Two branches continuously running with merges going both directions often. The key thing I am not sure about is how git will play out the commits and will it fill either branch with the commits from the other branch on merges or will it stay clean. I have used rebase before but it seems to end the branch and put all the commits into the master, or I did it wrong. Thanks for the help so far.

```
master
A--B--C-----H--I--J--M--N
       \   /    \
mobile  \ /      \
D--E--F--G--------K--L
```

Comment: If you were, like me, looking for how to do it with GitHub *client*: https://help.github.com/articles/merging-branches/

Comment: This question saved my life for centuries; Thanks for the great effort in taking time to set this wonderful question @Mr. EZEKIEL

Comment: In case you are working on a fork, you have to follow https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Comment: Googlers: the answers below, naturally, end up with `rebase` vs `merge` dilemma; see here for comparison: https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/git-rebase-vs-merge-which-better

Answer (score 651, accepted):

Yes, just do:

```sh
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout mobiledevicesupport
git merge master
```

to keep mobiledevicesupport in sync with master.

Then, when you're ready to put mobiledevicesupport into master, first, merge in master like above, then:

```sh
git checkout master
git merge mobiledevicesupport
git push origin master
```

and that's it.

The assumption here is that mobilexxx is a topic branch with work that isn't ready to go into your main branch yet. So only merge into master when mobiledevicesupport is in a good place.

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me, I guess I am not sure how dirty this would make the commit history, I will update my question with an example of what I think would happen.

Comment: You will have quite a few "merge commits", essentially git trying to resolve differences between your branches. if you're worried about that AND you're the only one using the branch then do a "git rebase master" instead of a "git merge master" AND DO NOT PUSH THE COMMITS TO THE REMOTE BRANCH. If you do you're going to find yourself doing a lot of force pushes (git push --force) to origin/mobiledevicesupport because you're going to (probably) always sending be it a history of commits that don't match what the remote branch has. more detail here http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, it sounds exactly like what I want. I added an illustration above to make it a little more clear but if what you are saying is true, then this should work out exactly how I want. Thank you.

Comment: This get the commit history messy, see my answer do it via rebase.

Comment: Sorry, I am failing to understand why "git checkout master" & "git pull" is required before "git merge master". Assuming that you are working on the mobiledevicesupport branch, I thought "git merge master" is sufficient? Can you please help me understand, please?

Comment: @oneworld to make sure you have the latest version of master. You can accomplish the same thing by just doing a `git pull origin master` from the mobiledevicesupport branch

Comment: Reviewer's note to the suggested edit author: please do not confuse context of a decade-old answer on a question asking about *master* branch just because you prefer "main" over "master".

Answer (score 52):

Whenever you want to get the changes from master into your work branch, do a `git rebase <remote>/master`. If there are any conflicts. resolve them.

When your work branch is ready, rebase again and then do `git push <remote> HEAD:master`. This will update the master branch on remote (central repo).

Comment: What is the pros/cons of doing it this way instead of as in the accepted answer?

Comment: Sane until you spend 5 hours in rebase hell

Comment: This is true only if your branch is on a private repository. Never rebase something that has been pushed upstream. This is why: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Comment: The problem with rebasing being a rewrite of the history is that the rebased commit's SHAs are changed and thus you cannot rely on the output of (e.g.) `git branch --contains <commit>`.

Answer (score 27):

concept47's approach is the right way to do it, but I'd advise to merge with the --no-ff option in order to keep your commit history clear.

```
git checkout develop
git pull --rebase
git checkout NewFeatureBranch
git merge --no-ff master
```

Comment: More info and graphics on `--no-ff`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer via git merge will get the job done but leaves a messy commit history, correct way should be 'rebase' via the following steps (assuming you want to keep your feature branch in sync with develop before you do the final push before PR).

1 `git fetch` from your feature branch (make sure the feature branch you are working on is update to date)

2 `git rebase origin/develop`

3 if any conflict should arise, resolve them one by one

4 use `git rebase --continue` once all conflicts have been dealt with

5 `git push --force`

Comment: This is both hard to read and hard to understand. Please update your answer and use proper code markdown, to separate out your comments from the commands.

Comment: Recommend to use `git push --force-with-lease` instead of `git push --force`

Answer (score 9):

Yeah I agree with your approach. To merge mobiledevicesupport into master you can use

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master //Get all latest commits of master branch
git merge mobiledevicesupport
```

Similarly you can also merge master in mobiledevicesupport.

Q. If cross merging is an issue or not.

A. Well it depends upon the commits made in mobile* branch and master branch from the last time they were synced. Take this example:
After last sync, following commits happen to these branches

```
Master branch: A -> B -> C [where A,B,C are commits]
Mobile branch: D -> E
```

Now, suppose commit B made some changes to file a.txt and commit D also made some changes to a.txt. Let us have a look at the impact of each operation of merging now,

```
git checkout master //Switches to master branch
git pull // Get the commits you don't have. May be your fellow workers have made them.
git merge mobiledevicesupport // It will try to add D and E in master branch.
```

Now, there are two types of merging possible

1. Fast forward merge
2. True merge (Requires manual effort)

Git will first try to make FF merge and if it finds any conflicts are not resolvable by git. It fails the merge and asks you to merge. In this case, a new commit will occur which is responsible for resolving conflicts in a.txt.

So Bottom line is Cross merging is not an issue and ultimately you have to do it and that is what syncing means. Make sure you dirty your hands in merging branches before doing anything in production.

Comment: So cross merging like this isn't an issue?

Comment: Cross merging is what we say syncing and is not an issue unless the commits in both branches does not cause any conflicts. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 8):

Run the following commands:

```
$ git checkout mobiledevice
$ git pull origin master
```

This would merge all the latest commits to your branch. If the merge results in some conflicts, you'll need to fix them.

I don't know if this is the best practice but works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking in the right direction. Merge master with mobiledevicesupport continuously and merge  mobiledevicesupport with master when mobiledevicesupport is stable. Each developer will have his own branch and can merge to and from either on master or  mobiledevicesupport depending on their role.

Answer (score 0):

```
using yourBranch = mobiledevicesupport;
```

Keeping *yourBranch* in sync with `master` consists of two important details:

1. update the *yourBranch* version in the cloud according to `master`
2. update the *yourBranch* version on your PC according to `master`

### How To:

Assuming *yourBranch* is behind `master`

1. create a merge request from `master` to *yourBranch* (e.g. via
   GitLab web UI)
2. accept/solve the merge request from `master` to *yourBranch* (e.g.
   via GitLab web UI)

- now you have changes from `master` in *yourBranch*
- this has loaded `master` changes to *yourBranch* on remote (in the cloud) but not locally yet

3. update the old version of *yourBranch* which you have locally (on
   your PC)

- make sure you are now locally interacting with your branch
- `git fetch` will check for changes
- `git status` will tell you the status of your local repository (of your local *yourBranch*) - e.g. 5 commits behind master
- `git pull` will download the new updated version from the cloud (from "remote") where changes from `master` are added - now you will be in sync with master also in the local repository (on your machine)