# Syncing 2 branches after git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

How do I keep 2 Git branches in sync?

I currently have a `master` branch and a `gh-pages` branch as well as the respective remotes. Both, `master` and `gh-pages` branch shared the same commit id whenever I committed as follows:

```
git checkout master
git commit -am "message"
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
```

My log looked like so (achieved with `git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate`):

[image: single-tracked-graph]

After a merge conflict, which I resolved, each merge receives its own commit as such:

[image: double-tracked-graph]

My question is, how can I align the 2 branches so that merges will happen as previously on a single 'graph-track'?

I have tried to `pull` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329776/how-to-keep-a-git-branch-in-sync-with-master), but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like commit `50b6dec` was added to the `gh-pages` branch, and commit `e43c01f` was made on `master` at the same time, and this is what caused the merge conflict.

Because of that, `gh-pages` had 1 commit that `master` did not have. So any time you merged after that, Git was not able to do a fast-forward merge. (The fast-forward merges is what gave you the linear history you had before.) Thus, the solution is:

```
git checkout master
git merge gh-pages
```

To prevent this from happening again in the future, change your process to this:

```
git checkout master
git commit -am "message"
git checkout gh-pages
git merge --ff-only master
```

The `--ff-only` flag will abort the merge with an error if `gh-pages` has any commits that `master` doesn't have.

---

If you want to rewrite history so that it is as if this never happened, you can do that too.

First, ensure you are on `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Now rebase:

```
git rebase 50b6dec
```

You'll have to resolve that conflict again. When finished, do:

```
git rebase --continue
```

When the rebase is complete, you will have to force-update `origin`:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

You'll also have to move the `gh-pages` branch. Do:

```
git branch -f gh-pages master
git push --force-with-lease origin gh-pages
```

This will give you a history that looks something like this:

```
* f218f70' (HEAD -> master) Added Scatterplot functionality to check ratings
* cb79b79' Squashed bug
* fcf0d8a' Small change
* e43c01f' Small change
* 50b6dec Small change
* a217267 Small change
```

Obligatory **warning**: Since a rebase rewrites history, this can be dangerous / disruptive for anyone else working on this branch. Be sure you clearly communicate what you have done with anyone you are collaborating with.

Comment: Many thanks @ScottWeldon for a great and thorough answer - solving not only my main but also my unspoken side-problem regarding a clean history...