# Best approach for Git repo template with multiple branches?

Tags: git, github

I want to start a **Git repo** to be used as a basis for a new web development project with a series of pre-configured and prepared technologies (npm project, templates or views, bundlers, preprocessors, plugins, linters ...).

Also, I want to use a branch to adapt the same idea with **different alternative technologies** (react, vue, preact, etc...)

Having several branches with different alternative technologies, if I want to make a change that only affects that technology, I do it only in that branch, but ...
If I want to make a common change in all branches (a file that affects all technologies or, for example, the update of some package to a new version)

Questions:

- What is the best way to make a change that affects ALL branches?
- Could someone tell me a good approach to do this in Git?

Comment: You may find useful these answers:
[How to keep a git branch in sync with master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329776/how-to-keep-a-git-branch-in-sync-with-master)

Answer (score 2):

Create 3 branches:

1. master branch - this is your first branch with all your common stuff.
2. feature 1 branch
3. feature 2 branch

If you want to make a change which is common to both. Then make that change/commit in master branch and then rebase your feature 1 & feature 2 branches with master branch. Run this command on both feature branches.

```
git branch origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition of rebasing your branches in order to include the latest evolution of a common file, you can also create a GitHub repository based on a template.

GitHub allows to [create a new repository from a template repository](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-repository-from-a-template)

And [since March 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-03-31-include-all-branches-when-creating-a-repository-from-a-template/), the new repository can include *all branches* of the template repository.

That means you can define your repository used as a basis for a new web development project with a series of pre-configured and prepared technologies, with its multiple branches as a GitHub template repository.
And then create new GitHub repositories for new projects, based on your original repository.