# git - update feature branch from master

Tags: git

Let's say I have a `feature` branch derived from `master`. Master is ahead several commits. I want to include lastest updates from `master` into my `feature` branch.

What is the correct approach?

1. `git pull`
2. `git pull --rebase`
3. `git pull origin feature`
4. `git pull origin master`
5. `git rebase origin/master`
6. `git merge origin/master`
7. Something else?

Sorry for lame question, but I really do have little bit of a mess in these commands. Description of the differences between the commands would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep a branch synchronized/updated with master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329776/how-to-keep-a-branch-synchronized-updated-with-master)

Comment: @evolutionxbox that specific question mentions that the branch in question is "a continuous branch", which would lean the best answer towards `merge`, whereas this question, specifying a feature branch without any additional context, would probably lean towards `rebase`. Since both are  presented in the top answers to that other question, I'm not opposed to that being the dup, though, I assume there is probably a better dup match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git rebase origin/master is the answer to your question.

Comment: It's one of many correct answers. Also, if `origin/master` hasn't been updated (with fetch), this will do nothing

Comment: git rebase or git merge are possible answers but git rebase is clean and the best fit for this question.

Comment: This question [has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329776/how-to-keep-a-branch-synchronized-updated-with-master)