# How to check if core files have been modified or not in magento?

Tags: magento

How can I check if the core files have been modified or not in magento.
I searched on Google for this.i found following solution [Quickly check if Magento core files are modified](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/quickly-check-if-magento-core-files-are-modified/)

But where to run this command and how?

Can we run this command on localhost?

Comment: Open a terminal/shell to the server and enter the `diff` command mentioned in the article (using your folder names of course).

Comment: Additionally, you should use git and github version control to track changes. My answer here has a couple great links as resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff/14865661#14865661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a separate folder on your system, unzip the Magento installer file into it so you have a fresh, unchanged copy of your current version's code.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/download under the release archives tab

And then run `diff` in a SSH session from the command line to compare the app/code/core files of your current running version against your fresh, unadulterated copy.

`diff -qrbB untainted_magento developer_mucked_magento`

Comment: what if the client websites have patched applied