# Git branches on a solo project

Tags: git

Is there any reason to create branches for features in a solo git repo? When I merge them back into master, they fast-forward and there is no real evidence that I even branched in the first place. Should I even bother?

Comment: well they don't have to fast-foward if you want to keep the history.  I find it very handy to use them on solo stuff as well. pretty much for all the same reasons you use them with multiple devs.

Comment: If you only ever work on one feature branch at a time, you will get fast-forward merges unless you specifically request a non-fast-forward merge. However, if you are working on one feature, get an inspiration to try something else, and use a separate branch to experiment, then maybe work on a different feature, then create another branch to fix a bug, etc., you will start to see non-fast-forward merges, even in a solo project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Branches can be really useful, even on a solo project. They allow you to develop new features in isolation (if need be) while easily allowing you to throw out work, and/or keep it separated from mainline development (so you can start new features from a clean, stable portion of your codebase).

(You can also prevent fast-forward merges by passing the `--no-ff` flag to `git merge`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can merge without fast-forwarding, check e.g. [What is the difference between `git merge` and `git merge --no-ff`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff)

And answering your question, I use branches in my solo projects e.g. to isolate experimental features. I might want to switch from Bootstrap to Zurb or from Knockout to Angular and a separate branch gives me a peace of mind.