# Is it safe to always git merge --no-ff (no fast-forward)?

Tags: git

I'd like to do no-ff merges by default. But am I giving up any safety, as is the case when using rebase?

Comment: What kind of safety are you thinking of?  With the reference to `rebase` are you alluding to the work it makes for others who already have your existing commit history, when you "rewrite your history"?

Comment: Fast forward merges afaik are the safest in that you will never lose data. I don't know the details of rebase, but I understand that used improperly, one *can* lose information.

Comment: I think you *are* referring to "history rewriting", then.  In which case, not a problem: a non-ff merge simply adds a new commit and moves a branch label.  A fast-forward merge moves the label to an existing (but forward) commit.  Both are "safe" because they do not "remove commits".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to always use --no-ff so history is retained, in fact, that is the standard we use at my job, take a [look at this document where we explain our git workflow](http://www.cakedc.com/git-workflow)

And here is a [another explanation given here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff)