# How to mark important events / milestones in Git history?

Tags: git, github, milestone

I have a repo consisting of files, related to four Ruby homework task. My fifth task is to refactor each of the previous four tasks the best way I can and mark each small refactoring as a single git commit, so that when one opens the git history, they could easily see what has changed (like `Use map instead of each`, `Rename instance variable`, etc.).  I have a branch, called `task-1` and now I am done with my commits for the first task. I want to merge it to `master`. Then I will make a new branch `task-2` and when ready, will merge it to `master`. But I want to have a clear indicator where commits, related to task 1 finish and commits for task 2 begin in git history. One way would be to amend the commit message of my last commit to include `..and finish task 1`, but I was wondering if there is some more intelligent way. Another way I though of, was to make a minor change, like add a space somewhere and use the commit message for this commit. What is the proper way to mark important events / milestones in git / Github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tagging is probably something you want to do, but if you want something in your commit log, the following may work:

You could use the no fast-forward tag when merging your branch. This adds a specific commit for the merging, and you could add 'finish task 1' to the commit message. So for instance you would do:

```
git merge task-1 --no-ff
```

And then you have a clear indication of where this branch was merged in.

I hope I understood your question properly, and this helps you out.

Comment: After talking to people and seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff) I realised you had the best answer.

Answer (score 9):

Use `git tag` to mark important milestones in your code.

Example - `git tag -a v1` will tag the current code as v1. You can always checkout this code by running `git checkout v1`

`git tag -l` can list all your tags.

Finally, remember to push your tags to the remote repository - `git push --tags`

Comment: You probably want to include the `-a` option to create an annotated tag instead of a lightweight one.

Comment: But if you `git checkout <tag>` later on, you end up with a `Detached HEAD`.  Is there a way of simply assigning a name to a particular commit (like an alias to the hash a commit generates) with no strings attached?

Comment: Can I run 'git diff' against a tag to see changes since the tag?

Answer (score 4):

I believe [git tags](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging) are best suited for your purpose.