# Merge branch into master

Tags: git, merge, git-extensions

I have created a branch out of the master branch where I have done different changes. But meanwhile, I have done a few changes to the master branch as well. Every time I try to merge the second branch into the main branch, the changes I have done to the main branch get overwritten by the second branch.

What is the correct way of doing the merge?

Note that I am using Git Extensions.

Comment: `the changes I have done to the main branch get overwritten` are you sure git doesn't report the conflicting changes as merge conflicts?

Comment: It didn't report any conflicts... If it has any importance, I have used the method from the accepted answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git

Comment: Try `git merge --no-ff`. Extensive info on that topic [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff