# git pull request with --no-ff flag

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to follow this model: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

And trying to understand how a merge like this would work from a pull request on Github... specifically the "--no-ff" flag:

```
git merge --no-ff hotfix-1.2.1
```

Additionally, after the PR request has been merged on Github, what is the best way to bring those updates into my local master branch? Would it just be:

```
git pull github-remote-branch
```

Comment: there is good explanation on `--no--ff` flag here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff

Comment: the second part of your question, normally I just do: `git checkout master`, then `git pull`

Comment: When using the git-flow workflow with GitHub's pull requests, have a look into the git extension [HubFlow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull request merges on GitHub always create a new commit, so they already act like `git merge --no-ff ...`.

> [A]fter the PR request has been merged on Github, what is the best way to bring those updates into my local master branch?

If your local `master` branch is set up to track the remote `master` branch, just do

```
git checkout master
git pull --ff-only
```

This will abort with an error if you have commits on local `master` branch that aren't on the remote `master` branch. (The default without `--ff-only` would have been to merge.)

Comment: my local git has a few remotes set up. how do i know which remote my local master is tracking against? right now i push my local master branch to github and to heroku.

Comment: if i wanted to explicitly state which remote to pull from how would i do that with the --ff-only flag?

Comment: To see the name, URLs and other details about the remote of the branch that local `master` branch is tracking, use `git remote show $(git config --get branch.master.remote)`.

Comment: You can combine the `--ff-only` option with explicitly naming the remote to pull from: `git pull github-remote-branch --ff-only`