# How, do I update the master branch to point to the tip of another branch if the master has had no knew commits since the other branch diverged?

Tags: git

I have a master branch and a feature branch. There have been no new commits in the master branch since the feature branch diverged. Now, I have finished the feature branch. How, do I update the master branch to point to the tip of the feature branch? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply merge feature into master: the merge will be a fast-forward one, meaning master HEAD will be updated to feature's HEAD

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

See more at "[What is the difference between `git merge` and `git merge --no-ff`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717431/6309)".

From [this article](https://www.defproc.co.uk/blog/2012/git-un-merge/):

[image: https://www.defproc.co.uk/blog/uploads/2012/05/ff-merge-300x212.png]

Comment: Thanks. I understand.