# is there a difference between a --squash merge and a --no-ff merge if the source (feature) branch is deleted shortly after?

Tags: git

Is there a difference, regarding the final state of the repository, between a --squash merge and a --no-ff merge if the source (feature) branch is deleted immediately afterwards?

The --no-ff merge commit will contain the same changes as the squash merge commit, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine the commits as nodes in a graph (because they *are* nodes in a graph).

Before you do anything else, you have a situation that looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

or perhaps like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- feature
```

If you now choose to run `git checkout master; git merge --no-ff feature`, the result will be a new commit on `master`—we'll call this commit `M` for Merge even though the next letter available is L—that looks like:

```
...--F--G--H---------M   <-- master
            \       /
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

(or similar).  The *first* parent of new commit `M` is existing commit `H`: the one that *was* the tip of `master` before.  The *second* parent of new commit `M` is existing commit `K`: the one that was, and still is, the tip of `feature`.

(If your starting graph looks like the second example, where the first commit that `feature` shares with `master` is `G` instead of `H`, the `--no-ff` argument is not required.  Git *must* do a true merge, so it will.  If your starting graph looks like the first example, the `--no-ff` forces Git to make a true merge even though the common starting point commit is already the tip of `master`.)

---

If you run `git merge --squash` instead of `git merge --no-ff`, you get this instead:

```
...--F--G--H---------S   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K   <-- feature
```

where we can call the new commit `S` for squash instead of `M` for merge.  Commit `S` is *exactly like `M`* in terms of *content*.  The key difference is that commit `S` has just *one* parent: commit `H`.

Your final action will be to delete the *name* `feature`.  So let's draw that, for both cases

```
...--F--G--H---------M   <-- master
            \       /
             I--J--K
```

and:

```
...--F--G--H---------S   <-- master
            \
             I--J--K
```

Now, `git log` and other Git commands *find* commits by starting at the *branch names*, which point to one specific *tip* commit like `M` or `S`, and then working backwards.  A commit that cannot be *found* may as well not *exist*.  So after about a month, Git will clean up and remove the unfindable commits in the second graph, leaving you with:

```
...--F--G--H---------S   <-- master
```

That is the ultimate difference between a squash merge and a true merge: a true merge retains the full history, including the individual commits that led to producing the merge.  A squash merge discards the history that led to *producing* the squash merge, keeping only a single commit that achieves the same effect—as if whoever wrote the squash merge code did it by sitting down with the code from `H`, writing everything as a single commit, and committing it.

Comment: Great explanation, how does the git log look like in the case of a true merge? Are the commits from both branches possibly interleaved (as if sorted by commit time). What about the commits on the feature branch that would have caused a merge conflict, but never did because the main branch was modified afterwards, yet before the final merge? Would the chronological ordering of the commits still make sense then?

Comment: @JornVanloofsvelt: See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering), but it's a little incomplete. What is left out of the description is that the actual implementation inside `git log` is to use a priority queue. The priority queue initially contains entries for every commit you named at the start: `git log master dev` picks out the two commits identified by `master` and `dev` and puts them in the queue, or `git log` with no arguments picks out the one commit identified by `HEAD` and puts that in the queue. Then...

Comment: ... upon taking a commit out of the queue and visiting it, the revision-walker adds the *parents* of that commit to the queue (unless they're already there/visited). The priority of the parents in the queue, and all other commits already in the queue if any, is affected by the sorting options. The effect of all of this is that for simple linear chains, `git log` starts at the end (1 commit in queue), removes the 1 commit, shows it, puts its 1 parent in, removes the 1 parent, shows it ....  So you only see the effect of this queue if you start from more than one commit or reach a merge.

Comment: The *default* sort is "by committer date", so the answer to your question ("possibly interleaved, as if sorted by committer time") is: yes. But there are options to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, changes will be the same as well as the resulting codebase.

What will be different is commit history. It could impact some log outputs, and the squash route will make original commits unavailable for inspection after the feature branch deletion.

In the other hand, the no-ff route will feature a somewhat more verbose history.

Comment: When using the --no-ff route, won't the original commits be unreachable as well, after feature branch deletion?

Comment: @JornVanloofsvelt No, they will be incorporated in the destination branch (master?) history.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the feature branch (as a pointer) might be deleted, but the commits of that feature branch will still exist and show up in the history of the master branch when running git log. Is that right?

Coming from TFS I expected all changes of the feature branch to be condensed in the merge commit. And that the history of the master branch would not show commits of the feature branch.

What if you inspect the changeset of one of those commits, won't it show what branch it belonged to? But since that branch is deleted ...

Comment: @JornVanloofsvelt No, branches are just lightweight pointers in git, they designate a commit and that's all. Only commits do matter in the end. The merge commit doesn't incorporate changes brought by previous commits, it only allows git to retrace history by forming an ancestry chain. And no, a commit never "belongs" to any branch. It is said "reachable" by any number of branches, number which can also be zero.