# Different commit number after PR completion to master branch

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I'm trying to create a Pull Request in GitHub repository from one (example: develop) branch to master branch. The commit number in master branch is different from commit number in develop branch after PR completion.

Commit in develop branch:

[image]

Commit in master branch after PR completion:

[image]

Is there a way to make sure that the commit number **won't change** after PR completion? It **stays the same** as in develop branch?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Make sure you are using the **Create a merge commit** option when accepting the pull request. This will merge the original commits unchanged.

On the other hand, the **Squash and merge** and **Rebase and merge** options will create new (but equivalent) commits with different hashes than the original commits.

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/merging-a-pull-request

---

You asked in the comments:

> I want only commits from develop to master on PR completion (same commit number, no extra commits). Is that possible?

In principle, this is possible in Git, by doing a *fast-forward* merge. However, as the above mentioned page states,

> Pull requests are merged using [the `--no-ff` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge)

so this is not possible by using the GitHub UI. As the maintainer of the source repository, you would have to manually do this by using the corresponding Git commands:

In your local copy of the repository,

- fetch the new commits from the forked repository,
- do the fast-forward merge (you can enforce it by using the `--ff-only` option for the `git merge` command),
- and then push them to GitHub.

Further reading: [What is the difference between `git merge` and `git merge --no-ff`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069061/what-is-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there's no way to force a commit hash in Git. Unless the commits in `develop` apply "as-is" to `master` (i.e., no changes where committed to `master` since `develop` was branched out of it), when merging to `master` the commits would have to be rebased or merged, and you'll get a different commit hash.