# Avoid adding empty merges

Tags: git, merge

I have a project which is also a NuGet package. Because of this, it lives on 2 branches: `master`, which is used for releasing new official versions, and `development`, where the actual development takes place. When we want to release a new version, we simply merge commits from `development` to `master`.
Our package releasing process includes (and requires) tagging commits. Now, the problem is: in the past when we merged from `development` to `master`, the git history for `master` would contain only commits from `development`, there were no merge commits (so it'd always add `n` commits to the history).
However, at some point somebody on the team started doing weird things with branches in this repository and now whenever we merge to `master`, an empty merge commit is added on top (so it results in `n+1` commits added to `master` history). It contains no files changed, it simply is there. This is mildly annoying, but the real problem here is that now the package tag ends up on the merge commit, something we do not want.
The question is: how can this be fixed so that we no longer get these empty merge commits every time branch is merged into `master` branch?

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but some people like to always have a merge commit, even when a fast-forward takes place.  This is probably why you have this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, the history of `master` has diverged from that of `development`. This divergence can be as small as a commit that was rebased to amend the commit message, author, or sign-off. *Even if the trees of the two branches are exactly the same, the history remains different*. Consequently, `git` cannot perform a fast-forward merge where it only updates `master` to point at the latest commit in `development`. Instead, a real merge commit is created to record the difference in history between `master` and `development`.

If the above description is correct, you can easily fix this situation by merging `master` into `development` once, ideally right after merging `development` into `master`.

After this merge (which should be a fast-forward if it happens right after a release-merge), `master` will again be a part of the history of `development`, so future merging of `development` into `master` will fast-forward `master` to the current state of `development` again.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is perform fast-foward merges. A fast foward merge can only take place if all changes on your `development` branch were made on top of the latest commit on  `master`. In this case, if you call `git merge` with `--ff-only`, the `master` branch pointer will be set directly to the latest commit of `development`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701292/git-fast-forward-vs-no-fast-forward-merge#6701322) and linked questions for details on ff and non-ff merges.

The opposite of this would be the `--no-ff` argument, which enforces a merge commit even if none is necessary.

Be aware that if you use GitLab, GitHub or something similar, there may be settings to ajust if merge commits are enforced or not.