# how do you separate the lines of each branch on git?

Tags: git, github, gitk

I want to separate each line in the branch to make it easier for me to read it. How do you change one image to make it look like Figure 2?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: I guess the short answer is `by branching`. You create branches for different things and then you merge when needed. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: Merge without fast forwarding or rebasing

Comment: i.e., `git merge --no-ff feature-branch`. This creates a separate merge commit, allowing you to see the tree nicely. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701292/git-fast-forward-vs-no-fast-forward-merge/6701322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: each of the remote tracking branches are part of the same history, they are direct descendant of the master branch.

So there is no "separate line" to see here, unless you [create one by switching to each branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---guess) and pushing an empty artifical commit:

```
git switch register # creates the register branch tracking origin/register
git commit --allow-empty -m "artificial empty commit"
git push -u origin register
```

But again, you should not need that in your case (linear history)