# Possible issue after doing `Squash and Merge`?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I used `Squash and Merge` for merging `dev` branch into `main` because I didn't want some of the commit messages from `dev` branch to appear in `main`
But now I found out that `main` is 1 commit ahead of dev.
And the graph shows that there is no connection between `dev` and `main`. This is something I have not seen before, and I have used **Squash and merge** for the first time

### The graph of the repository:

[image: git extension generated graph]

Now, should I do:

1. `git checkout dev`
2. `git rebase main`

Else, what should I do after I did **Squash and Merge** to prevent unexpected problems from occurring.

Here, I cannot understand the situation. I may be thinking wrong. In that case, please tell me what is correct.

### My workflow:

I have two long-lived branches `main` & `dev`. Then I have short-lived branches `feature`, `bug`, `hotfix`, etc. The `main` branch always remains production-ready. And I will delete the last `feature` branch when I merge `dev` into `main`

### My `dev` branch looks like this:

[image: dev graph]

### The `main` branch looks like this:

[image: main graph]

Note:

- I am a newbie in git. So, my thinking can be wrong. If this is the case, please point out my mistake and tell me what is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have two conflicting desires:

> I have two long-lived branches `main` & `dev`.

You didn't state it, but typically you want these long lived branches to sync up periodically, and that is what you attempted to do. But that means you can't do this:

> ... because I didn't want some of the commit messages from dev branch to appear in main.

By squashing you got the *code* to be the same in both branches, but you really need to sync up the commits as well, or else you'll have a lot of painful merges in the future. Unless you're willing to rewrite `dev` periodically from `main`, you're going to need to modify your process to make sure all commits into `dev` are "proper" since they will eventually end up in `main` also.

From now on, I would recommend merging `dev` into `main` with a regular merge (either fast-forward or with `--no-ff`, that's up to you). In the future, follow this rule of thumb:

> It's OK to use squash-merge when merging feature branches into `dev` and/or `main`, but you should never use squash-merge when merging long lived branches together. This will prevent you from having the problem again in the future.

To fix your current situation, based on the discussion in the comments we know you are OK with rewriting both `dev` and `main` right now, and you are happy with the commits on `main`. Therefore I would suggest the following action to clean it up:

```
# rewrite the squash-merge commit message on main to be more meaningful
git switch main
git commit --amend -m "Import web app and modify profile"
git push --force-with-lease

# reset dev to look like main
git switch dev
git reset --hard main
git push --force-with-lease
```

Comment: Can I undo it? Or should I do `git checkout dev`⇒`git rebase main` as I said in the question

Comment: @KnowledgeMan If other people are already using the updated `origin/main` with your merge, I wouldn't undo it. I updated the answer with steps for moving forward.

Comment: @KnowledgeMan Also, best practice is to never rebase long lived branches either. You can rebase or squash-merge feature branches into `dev` or `main`, but never rebase or squash-merge `dev` or `main` into each other.

Comment: No, only I am working right now. there is another collaborator. But he has not done anything yet. So, in this case can I undo this. Also, is it good idea to get rid of the extra commits that come from the dev branch by squashing them in the main branch after normally merging dev into main

Comment: @KnowledgeMan OK, if you can rewrite both of your branches, I would do this: rewrite `dev` to be the way you want it to be. Then reset (hard) `main` to the commit it was on before you merged in `dev`. Then redo the merge of `dev` into `main`. Then force push out both branches.

Comment: Can you add this to the answers, and be specific about the steps and commands to be used --as I am not able to understand the comment completely

Comment: @KnowledgeMan `dev` currently has 4 commits. Sounds like you want 2 commits there. What do you want your commit message to be for the second commit? You have "Import the whole web app from external source" and "Modify the Profile". Are you sure you want to even squash those together? Maybe what you want is 3 commits? Also, the merge commit about the PR isn't necessarily bad to keep around either. In my projects I keep those on purpose. Then someone could go look up PR #1 to see the code review comments and discussion, and previous versions of that branch before it was merged.

Comment: Before this, I have merged `one_feature` branch into `dev` with `--no-ff` (here I was wanting to do what **Squash & merge** does). So, then to prevent those commits of `one_feature` branch that are now in `dev` branch  from getting into main I did **Squash & merge** for `dev` into `main`. And then due to my intuition, I asked this question.

Comment: @KnowledgeMan Yes, understood. Let me rephrase my question. From a commit standpoint, you are happy with your commits on `main`, correct? But the commit message on `main` isn't very useful, it currently says, "Request to merge dev into main (#2)". We're getting off topic here from the original question, but it's good practice to have meaningful commit messages. Since we're rewriting your branch anyway, we might as well put a nice message there...

Comment: Yes. And also do something to sync dev and main.

Comment: @KnowledgeMan that 2nd commit on `main` does two things: "Import the whole web app from external source" and "Modify the Profile". If you want all of those changes in a single commit, then the commit message should try to capture that information.

Comment: This is not the main problem. I just want to solve the potential issue that can happen due to **Squash & Merge**

Comment: @KnowledgeMan got it. I edited the answer to include the fixup steps, and an explanation of when you should and should not use squash-merge in the future.

Comment: Can I now work normally like: `git checkout -b feature dev`⇒make commits in `feature`⇒`git rebase dev`⇒`git switch dev`⇒`git merge --squash feature`⇒`git push origin dev`⇒`git switch main`⇒`git merge dev --no-ff`. So, this will be the correct wrokflow, according to my current understanding after your help

Comment: @KnowledgeMan Yes, that workflow will work. Note due to `--no-ff` merges, `main` will get ahead of `dev` by 1 commit every time you do that merge, and that's fine. At some point you could merge `main` back into `dev` to sync it back up (perhaps if you have a hotfix into `main` that skipped the `dev` branch.)

Comment: Very late,.. but saved my live.