# With dvcs/git, is a single commit preferred over multiple, small, thematic commits?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

This may not be a git specific question, but it comes up in the context of git. The idea may apply more broadly to other vcs's.

I am working on a small project in which I am currently the only developer. I'm getting used to using git, so I am wondering about best practices. As I implement new features/functions, I find that I work on multiple files, their examples, and documentation at once, such that my git status may report 15 files that have changed. But those files might relate to 3 different parts of the project.

Is it better to commit them in 3 separate parts, keeping the related files together, so that I could later go back and more easily find those commits. Or it is just as easy to commit them all at once with an appropriate message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One criteria that can help you make the right "amount" of commit is [`git bisect`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) or `git blame`: would a large commit be a nuisance when trying to `git bisect` in order to detect a bug?

That is what describes the "[Understanding the Git Workflow](http://sandofsky.com/blog/git-workflow.html)" blog post, when it describes "checkpoint commits" (too little commits capturing the code in a unstable state), or "`no-ff` commits" (which represents too many modification bundled together in one large commit).

Answer (score 7):

Its preferable to make commits atomic. That is, a commit represents one logical change to the project in question, and can stand alone.

This allows

1. Easy code inspection
2. `git bisect` to work correctly

Answer (score 2):

It can be difficult, and there are many differing views about "the one best workflow". Where possible it is better to

1. separate concerns - use a number of short lived separate branches, one per concern. You can always squash your commit sequence before the final merge and publishing to a more senior branch.
2. commit often - smaller steps make it easier to find where mistakes happened and why, and to align merges. Again you can squash after it works.
3. use the staging area and `git stash` to partition which work you place in each commit.
4. Don't worry too much about minor slip ups. Foresight only happens if you walk backwards..