# Git asking for a merge but i've no local commit

Tags: git, github

Today i noticed that git was asking me for a merge on my master branch. Which is suspicious since i never commit on the master branch. So i looked at the two history:

**LOCAL**

```
*   595ad41 (HEAD -> master) Merge pull request #201 from project/feature/awesome
|\  
| * f9e3bb4 (origin/feature/awesome) Title
| * b78866e Title
* | 6b93955 Title

[...]
```

**REMOTE**

```
*   f14ade3 (HEAD, origin/staging, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #205 from proect/fix/awesomeness
|\  
| * 67ae410 (origin/fix/awesomeness, fix/awesomeness) Fix awesomness
|/  
* 91384e6 [staging] Title
* ca04409 [staging] Title
*   73fe5ff Merge pull request #204 from project/fix/something
|\  
| * b31a9da (origin/fix/something, fix/something) fix newline
|/  
*   595ad41 (master) Merge pull request #201 from project/feature/awesome
|\  
| * f9e3bb4 (origin/feature/awesome) Title
| * b78866e Title
* | 6b93955 Title

[...]
```

So i thought that after a git pull my local version will be the same as my remote version. But instead git asked me for a merge message and generated the following:

```
*   83463ef (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'master' of github.com:org/project
|\  
| *   f14ade3 (origin/staging, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #205 from project/fix/awesomness
| |\  
| | * 67ae410 (origin/fix/awesomness, fix/awesomness) Fix awesomness
| |/  
| * 91384e6 Title
| * ca04409 Title
| *   73fe5ff Merge pull request #204 from project/fix/something
| |\  
|/ /  
| * b31a9da (origin/fix/something, fix/something) fix newline
|/  
*   595ad41 Merge pull request #201 from project/feature/awesome
|\ 
| * f9e3bb4 (origin/feature/awesome) Title
| * b78866e Title
* | 6b93955 Title

[ ... ]
```

Any idea on why and how to fix this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Likely the cause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798767/fast-forward-when-using-pull-and-no-ff-when-pull

Comment: Argg thanks this was the cause!