# Separate clones, or separate branches

Tags: git, workflow, branch

Hi guys : Im not particularly excited about git branches, but my organization uses them heavily.  In any case, I need to work on a branch of head.  In the past I have "switched" branches while developing in a single place, however, I feel like this gets confusing.

Is it common/idiomatic in git to simply have two separate git directories, one for a branch1, and another for branch2 ?

Or

Is it more common to have a single working directory, switching between branches in that directory .

Also, im curious about the benefits/drawbacks of these two approaches.  If either is completely ridiculous, please let me know as well - im somewhat new to git.

Comment: Learn how to use branches, and you may get excited about them.

Answer (score 4):

It is **very common to switch between branches**. If you have some unsaved changes, **use `git stash` command** (see in the documentation).

It is **very uncommon to have separate directories for different branches from the same repository** - this is unnecessary, inefficient and reasonable only if you have eg. two working applications / websites at the same time, one for each branch.

Answer (score 2):

Git makes branching easy -- use branches.

Having one directory per branch is woefully inefficient: it means you have two git repositories, and you'd need to keep both in sync.

Among other niceties, when you switch branches (using `git checkout branchname`), git *will only ever rewrite files which change between the two branches*. This is MUCH more efficient than a mechanism when you have to manage n directories.

If you want to create a branch off of master, just `git branch newbranch master` and `git checkout newbranch` -- or in one command, `git checkout -b newbranch master`.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind switching branches within *one* directory is sustained by:

- the **high frequency of merges between branches** which means:

  - the delta between your usual branches isn't very important
  - as a consequence of that small delta, the switch itself is very (very) fast)

.

- the **cost associated with the definition of a new environment for a different path** (which means your IDE -- Eclipse or Visual Studio -- projects and other configuration files might have to adjust to a new path.
  If everything is done within one directory, you only define your development environment once.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default/2850413#2850413