# when merging git branch, how to avoid the commits logs in a branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit

if another developer branches out on branch DEVELOPER_A, and makes a lot of commits on that branch, when he's done, I want to merge his work onto master. but I don't want all his small commits to show up on the master branch history, and only care about the last commit. 
so is there a way to "squash " his history on branch DEVELOPER_A when merging that branch?

I could get a patch on developer_A branch, and apply to master, but I'm afraid git will lose track of the fact that the result is merged from developer_A branch, and merely thinks that this is some independent change

Thanks
Yang

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599411/git-merge-no-commit-squash-difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in several ways, but the most obvious is to use a squashed merge.

```
git merge --squash <other_branch>
git commit
```

Note that git will pre-populate your merge commit message with the log messages from the squashed commits, but you are free to edit or delete the messages to suit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you want to clean up the history, not just mush everything together. The tool for that is git rebase (use with extreme care, and *never* on published stuff, as changing history creates havoc for your downstreams).

OTOH, it is very useful to have a detailed history (micro-commits) at hand for chasing bugs (look at git bisect).