# Branch issue when using EGit Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have master branch of the project. Then I want to add a new feature so I create a new branch called "new_feature", base on master branch. In new_feature branch, everything works fine and I want to delete some files that are no longer useful. But when I switch back to master branch  and merge with new_feature branch, these deleted files still exist.
Here is my question: what I have to do to make master branch is exactly the same as the new_feature branch so I can delete new_feature branch.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to check in the delete. In Eclipse, switch to the feature branch and open the Git Staging view to see changes that are still pending. File deletes get *staged* automatically, but not *committed*.

Required sequence is

Delete - commit - push - checkout other branch - merge - commit - push

Comment: Oops, I can't do it before. Now it works like magic. Maybe I forgot to commit the the deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

You need merge `new_feature` branch to `master`.

The steps are,

1. Switch to `master` branch
2. Team - Merge, select `new_feature` branch

Answer (score 0):

@Duc Le: You must merge your **new_feature** branch to your **master** branch to get all modified file in **new_feature** branch into **master** branch.

Maybe something like this you can follow :

1. Check your branch :

   $ git branch 
   new_feature * (your active branch)
   master
2. Switch to your **master** branch :

   $ git checkout master
3. Merge your **new_feature** to **master** branch without fast-forward mode:

   $ git merge --no-ff new_feature

[Explanation about merging without fast-forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't use Git command line. I use EGit instead, a plugin of Eclipse.

Comment: Owh ic, maybe you can read about merging in egit in http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Merging :)