# Forcing 'git merge' to declare all differences as a merge conflict

Tags: git, git-merge

In a 'git merge ' I would like any difference, even if not normally a merge conflict, to be considered a merge conflict.  Then, with 'git mergetool' I can see and resolve each and every difference.  I tried specifying '* -merge' in .gitattributes but that doesn't seem to have worked:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ ls
foo.c
$ git merge add-on
Updating a628824..2219552
Fast-forward
  0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar.c
$ cat .gitattributes 
* -merge
$ ls
bar.c   foo.c
```

For the above 'git merge add-on' I expected a merge conflict for 'bar.c' with no base version, no local version and a remote version. 
[edit] As suggested in one answer, a merge didn't occur above.  Here is a case where I forced a merge, still no desired merge conflict:

```
$ git merge --no-ff add-on
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bing.c
```

Note that in above 'bing.c' is actually empty; but, that isn't the problem because providing a non-empty file still gets merged.  [edit 2] I tried --no-commit with this result:

```
$ git merge --no-ff --no-commit add-on
Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#
#   new file:   boom.c
#
$ git mergetool
No files need merging
$ cat .gitattributes 
* -merge
```

What am I missing?  Is there a way to confirm that '.gitattributes' is getting used/read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't merge. Your command `git merge add-on` executed a "fast-forward", which means it just moved the branch head. This is because your `add-on` branch was descended from the tip of your `master` branch already, so no merge was needed. If you run `git log` you'll see there's no merge commit.

Basically, it looked like this before the merge:

```
              master
             /
o---o---o---o           add-on
             \         /
              o---o---o
```

and the merge just moved the `master` pointer to the end of the line:

```
                          master, add-on
                         /
o---o---o---o---o---o---o
```

If you want to force a merge, pass the `--no-ff` flag, as in `git merge --no-ff add-on`.

---

Upon further reflection, the `merge` attribute won't do what you want. This only applies to file-level merges, which means both sides of the merge has changes to the specific file. If only one side has changes (which is your case), no file-level merge is done and the changed file is accepted unconditionally.

Your best bet is probably to use `git merge --no-ff --no-commit add-on` to produce the merge but don't actually commit. You can now inspect the results and tweak them to your satisfaction before committing the merge. If you want to accept changes on a per-hunk basis you can do something like `git reset` to reset the index and then `git add -p` to do per-hunk staging.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried again with 'git merge --no-ff add-on' - still no desired merge conflict.

Comment: @GoZoner: There's no merge conflict because there were no file-level merges. Only one side of the merge had any changes to the file, so that side was chosen unconditionally. The `merge` attribute only applies when there's a file-level merge (e.g. both sides had changes and a merge driver needs to be invoked).

Comment: Right, but based on the git attributes documentation for 'merge unset', I expect that a merge conflict would be forced to occur.  Perhaps '* -merge' isn't the right way to get my desired behavior (every difference, even if normally merge-able, produces a conflict that I can then resolve explicitly with a 3-way merge - so that I can verify that the merge is semantically correct, not just textually correct).

Comment: @GoZoner: From the manpage: "The attribute merge affects how three versions of a file are merged when a *file-level merge* is necessary during git merge" (emphasis mine). You don't have a file-level merge. I updated my answer already with an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Yes, see it now and have confirmed.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try:

```
git merge --no-commit
```

Which will make GIT not commit the merge changes. Alternatively if you want it to commit when there are no conflict, but not to lose the source branch, it's no-ff:

```
git merge --no-ff
```

Both can be used if necessary.

More info here: [Why does git fast-forward merges by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried again with 'git merge --no-ff add-on' - still no desired merge conflict.

Comment: And did you try `--no-commit`? The fact that it doesn't commit gives you a chance to choose what to accept and what not to accept. You still won't get a *conflict* necessarily, because there is none.

Comment: I'll try but note that the help for gitattributes states "Unset: Take the version from the current branch as the tentative merge result, and declare that the merge has conflicts. This is suitable for binary files that do not have a well-defined merge semantics."  Declaring conflicts ought to stop the merge prior to any commit.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar desire and have been unable to do it with the automatic tools. Here is a semi automated solution:

From `master`, merge `add-on` and manually resolve changes:

Start with:

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit add-on
```

Then, for each changed file do:

```
git show master:path/to/file > from_master
git show add-on/to/file > from_add-on
kdiff3 --qall from_master from_add-on -o path/to/file
git add path/to/file
```

Finally,

```
git commit
```

#### Why this 90% solution?

This solution merges even in "obvious situations" and it doesn't force me to set .gitattributes so I can make "manual merge" behavior dependent on who I am merging from and why rather than on which files I am merging.