# Make a new branch from branch with clean commit history

Tags: git

I have one branch which has many unnecessary commits so I would like to branch from it to a version with clean history.

This is example:

```
Master:
commit1
commit2
commit3

BranchB:
commitB1
commitB2
commitB3
commitB4
commitB5
commitB6

After merge:
commit1
commit2
commit3
commitB1
commitB2
commitB3
commitB4
commitB5
commitB6
```

Instead of that I would like to have something like this:

```
commit1
commit2
commit3
commitB6
```

Is it possible to clone all the code from branch B (state after commit B6) and copy it to a new branch C with a new commit message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use git-merge --squash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308816/how-to-use-git-merge-squash)

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b branchc
git merge --no-ff branchb
```

then the merge commit incorporates changes of branchb from  b1-b6 on top of master.

Comment: Thanks! On more question. How to have different commit message than from b6? I would like to have a one commit message which would include short version of messages from b1 to b6.

Comment: @Cristiano actually I was right even if I was wrong, the merge commit is not b6, but a new commit, modifying the answer

Comment: Thank you but it seems it's not working. I still see old log messages.

Comment: @Cristiano then probably you need a --squash instead of no-ff as pointed out by Andrew C  , see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388813/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-no-ff-and-git-merge-squash)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch from current `master`

```
git checkout -b BranchC
```

Do a rebase interactive and remove the commits you don't want

```
git rebase -i commit3
```

In the rebase interactive editor it will look like this

```
pick commit3
pick commitB1
pick commitB2
pick commitB3
pick commitB4
pick commitB5
pick commitB6
```

delete the commits you don't want. The editor might look like this than.

```
pick commit3
pick commitB6
```

save and quit.

Hopefully `commitB6` does not depend on changes of `commitB1`..`commitB5`. Otherwise you have to resolve the conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

You can also do this, a cherry-pick

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b branchc
git cherry-pick commitB6
```