# git log not showing branches when you work alone in the project

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I have found that I only see branches and the right project topology when using either `gitk`, `sourcetree` or `git log` if I am collaborating with other developers.

But when I work alone and I create branches by using `git checkout -b branchName`, then I cannot see any branch in any of those visual representation tools.
It looks like I have been working only in master, no branches are represented.

What am I doing wrong? I expect to see my branches appearing, when I create them or merge them back with other branches or master.

Am I misunderstanding how git works?

Further explanation:

[image]

I expect to see something like this where all my branches are represented:

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: How exactly are you creating branches?

Comment: via using git checkout -b branchName

Comment: What output would you expect? `master` and `testingScroll` are both there, right next to each other. In your case they are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gitk`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)  takes the same arguments that [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

So if you want to see all (local) branches, you should at least use:

```
gitk --branches.
```

I like to see the remote branches as well:

```
gitk --branches --all
```

What the [OP prussian-blue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175555/prussian-blue) [didn't see was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637404/git-log-not-showing-branches-when-you-work-alone-in-the-project/15638269#comment22189451_15638269):

> What I want is to see something like the second screenshot, not the first one. I expect to see `testinscroll` **in parallel** to `master`, as `testingscroll` was branched out from `master` in the first commits of the project.

What I suspect (and answered) is:

> you won't see that, because the merge from `testingscroll` to `master` was a **fast-forward** one, as explained in "[Why does git use fast-forward merging by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default/2850413#2850413)" : `master` HEAD has just been moved to `testingscroll`, making the two branches identical.

What would preserve the two branches, keeping them separate until the merge, would be:

```
git merge --no-ff testingscroll
```

Comment: Sorry, tried this but still I see the same unexpected result, with no branches being represented. Please, take a look at the screenshot I posted in my last edit of this post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @prussianblue on what branch are you currently on? (what does `git branch` returns?). Your screenshot shows both `master` and `testinscroll` branches.

Comment: I am in master. Also tried switching to testingscroll branch and I see the same result. What I expect to see is my branch testingscroll in parallel to master, until the final merge in the last commit. Makes it sense?

Comment: @prussianblue so... what you see is correct then: both `master` and `testingscroll` are pointing to the same commit (fast-forward merge for `master`: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default/2850413#2850413)

Comment: Many thanks Vonc, I updated the post including a seconds screenshot. What I want is to see something like the second screenshot, not the first one. I expect to see testinscroll in parallel to master, as testingscroll was branched out from master in the first commits of the project.

Comment: @prussianblue you won't see that, because the merge from `testingscroll` to `master` was a fast-forward one, as explained in the link I mentioned before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default/2850413#2850413 : `master` HEAD has just been moved to `testingscroll`, making the two branches identical.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, this is the relevant answer! Cool! The answer was here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default/2850413#2850413 as you said! Git merge --no-ff branchName did exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @prussianblue Excellent! I have included those comments in the answer for more visibility.