# Merge fast-fowards to another branch and no commit record is created

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a *master* branch and *debug* branch. They are one commit apart. *debug* branch is branched from *master* and has one commit. When I merge them, git fast-fowards *master* branch to *debug* branch, not creating another commit as I am familiar. It is missing some information, namely comments, from the master branch (which becomes HEAD^ after the merge). I have several questions:

How come it does not create another commit with the comment that denotes branches have been merged?
What is the criteria for fast forward?
Should I be paranoid about the fast-foward merge and check it every time?
I do not think I have anything in `.gitconfig` file that may affect the behavior:

```
[merge]
    tool = fugitive
[push]
    default = upstream
[diff]
    tool = vimdiff
[mergetool "fugitive"]
    cmd = vim -f -c \"Gdiff\" \"$MERGED\"
[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

Comment: When you say that comments are missing, have you looked in the history? Anything you have committed will almost certainly be there somewhere. Fire up `gitk --all` and inspect the commit contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git will by default do a fast forward merge when the commit you are merging in points to the current commit as a parent (a Git commit (almost) always contain a pointer to it's parent(s), i.e. predecessor(s)).

Here, commit A is on develop and B is on master

```
C      <---       B      <---   A
older stuff       master        develop
```

After a fast forward merge (`git checkout master; git merge develop`):

```
C      <---       B      <---   A
older stuff                     develop
                                master
```

In this scenario there can be no conflicts.

Compare this to a more complex merge

```
C - B'
  \ 
    A'
```

Here B' and A' can have introduced changes in the same places, so conflicts can occur hand have to be able to be resolved in a merge commit M

```
C - B'-M
  \   /
    A'
```

If you do not want the default fast forward merge behavior you can use the --no-ff switch. `git merge --no-ff develop` on the first example above would produce.

```
C - B  -  M (master)
     \   /
       A
       develop
```

M is the merge commit that was forced. Master is at M and develop is at B.

People actually tend to be more paranoid about merges that are *not* fast forward, since they have the potential of creating buggy conflicts. If you wish to make sure that the merge only goes ahead if it will be a fast forward you can do `git merge --ff-only develop`

So, the Git behavior you are seeing is standard and there is nothing wrong with your `.gitconfig`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-use-fast-forward-merging-by-default) has more details.