# How to turn off fast-forwarding in Git?

Tags: git, deployment, bitbucket, pull-request

We are trying to use git in our project development.

We work from our private repositories, through pull-requests to main repository under another account.

To deploy to our hosting we use **ftploy.com**

We tested it, all works fine on first manual deploy, but it doesn't work automaticly, when we merge pull-request to our master branch.

I asked support for this problem, there is an answer:

> Currently, if you’re using Bitbucket and utilising merges you need to
>   turn off fast-forwarding on your local Git install.

Because i'm novice, i can't understand what should i do and how my local git install connected with our main repository on another account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to turn it off for a given branch:

```
git config branch.master.mergeoptions  "--no-ff"
```

For any branch:

```
git config merge.ff false
```

(from [`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))

Those commands are to be executed within the repo where you want the merge to *not* be fast-forwarded (see "[Why does git fast-forward merges by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850413/6309)").