# Merge multiple commits by different authors while maintaining author details in git blame

Tags: git, git-flow

Is there a way to merge several commits by different authors with Git.

So that a commit is used per feature that still allows others to see who wrote the each line of code.

Will using a tool like git-flow help facilitate this ?

ie;

#### branch *NewFeature10*

- feature UI
- feature Backend
- feature Admin
- feature AdminBackend

squash and merge these commits to master so master follows

#### branch *master*

- NewFeature10
- NewFeature9
- NewFeature8
- ...

Answer (score 0):

A commit has 1 and only 1 author.  The best you could achieve would be N commits for FeatureX, where N is the number of unique authors that worked on that feature.