# Git, merging branches git

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I can not understand why my merge is updating one commit... it look that it updating commit Add Color, not merging master with coins. Sublime doesn't pop out when i try to merge these branches. 
Anyone can help me? Moreover when i type git commit i have:

On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean

[image]

Comment: Doesn't "Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'" indicate that there's nothing to pull?

Comment: Could you give us a `git log --graph --decorate`? That will show branch heads and connections. Otherwise I'm not sure what your question is? It seems like a normal [fast-forward merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850369/why-does-git-fast-forward-merges-by-default#2850413) (ie. there is no merge necessary because there have been no changes to `master` since `coins` branched, so it just moves `master` to where `coins` is). Also, did you mean to merge `master` into `coins` and not `coins` into `master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but think there's two things going on here you might not fully understand.

First, I don't think `git merge master coins` does what you think it does.

`git merge master coins` ***does not*** say to merge `master` into `coins`. It says to merge `master` ***and*** `coins` into the currently checked out branch. That's because `master coins` is a list of branches to merge into the current branch. [From the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)...

> [git merge] incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their histories diverged from the current branch) ***into the current branch***.

If `master` is checked out, then it merges coins into master. If `coins` is checked out, then it merges `master` into `coins`. If something else is checked out you get what's called an "octopus merge" and all three, `master`, `coins`, and the current branch are merged together into what is probably a big mess.

As it stands, you merged with `master` checked out, so `git merge master coins` is the same as `git merge coins`. You merged `coins` into `master` which is, I think, what you wanted, but it could have gone bad.

So don't use that syntax; it can get you in trouble, and it's hard to know what actually happened by looking at the command history. Instead use `git checkout branch-to-merge-into; git merge branch-to-merge-from`. So if you want to merge from coins into master, `git checkout master; git merge coins`.

---

Next issue is about the fast-forward merge. This is something that Git does when there's no need for a merge, when the branches haven't diverged. For example, let's say you had this...

```
A - B - C - D - G [master]
         \
          E - F - H [feature]
```

Since `master` has changes which are not in common with `feature` (D and G), it must merge. So `git checkout master; git merge feature` results in a new merge commit.

```
A - B - C - D - G - I [master]
         \         /
          E - F - H [feature]
```

But if there were no new commits on `master`, you have this (`master` is pointing at C).

```
         [master]
A - B - C - E - F - H [feature]
```

`feature` is said to have not diverged from `master`. There's no need for a merge commit, so Git doesn't bother with one. When you do `git checkout master; git merge feature` it simply moves `master` to H.

```
                      [master]
A - B - C - E - F - H [feature]
```

Git can do this because "branches" are really just labels pointing at a commit. Now `master` and `feature` point at the same commit.

---

I recommend avoiding fast-forwards while merging feature branches because it loses important archeological information. Someone looking at the repository later cannot tell that E, F, and H were all done as a single branch.

I recommend to always merge feature branches with `git merge --no-ff`. This forces Git to make a merge commit and someone trying to figure out your code in the future can know that E, F, and H are all part of a greater whole.

```
A - B - C --------- I [master]
         \         /
          E - F - H [feature]
```

The merge commit, I, also gives you a place to describe the branch and add things like a link to the issue/bug/ticket describing what the branch was for.